# Add number to a grid Tikz LaTeX

Tags: latex, tikz

How do I add numbers outside the below grid. I tried the following code but it is not centred and I cannot put the number.

```
  \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{geometry}
    \geometry{hmargin=1cm,vmargin=1cm}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary {shapes.geometric, arrows, arrows.meta}
    \def\width{20}
    \def\hauteur{25}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[x=1cm, y=1cm]
    \draw[step=1mm, line width=0.1mm, black!5!white] (0,0) grid (\width,\hauteur);
    \draw[step=5mm, line width=0.2mm, black!10!white] (0,0) grid (\width,\hauteur);
    \draw[step=5cm, line width=0.5mm, black!10!black] (0,0) grid (\width,\hauteur);
    \draw[step=1cm, line width=0.3mm, black!15!white] (0,0) grid (\width,\hauteur);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: Instead of reinventing the wheel, have a look at pgfplots

Comment: samcarter is not my intention to plot. I have to do a very different diagram. See below pls.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try using a combination of the `\foreach` loop and the `\node` functionality. I added the source code below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{hmargin=1cm,vmargin=1cm}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary {shapes.geometric, arrows, arrows.meta}
    
\def\width{20}
\def\hauteur{25}
    
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[x=1cm, y=1cm]
    \draw[step=1mm, line width=0.1mm, black!5!white] (0,0) grid (\width,\hauteur);
    \draw[step=5mm, line width=0.2mm, black!10!white] (0,0) grid (\width,\hauteur);
    \draw[step=5cm, line width=0.5mm, black!10!black] (0,0) grid (\width,\hauteur);
    \draw[step=1cm, line width=0.3mm, black!15!white] (0,0) grid (\width,\hauteur);
    
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    %%%%%%%%%%%% ADD THE PART BELOW %%%%%%%%%%%%
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \foreach \x in {0, ..., \width} {%
      % Bottom
      \node[anchor=north] at (\x,0) {\x};
      
      % Top
      \node[anchor=south] at (\x,\hauteur) {\x};
    }
    
    \foreach \y in {0, ..., \hauteur} {%
      % Left
      \node[anchor=east] at (0,\y) {\y};
      
      % Right
      \node[anchor=west] at (\width,\y) {\y};
    }
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This will produce the following output:

[image: Output grid with numbers around it]

Of course you can still adjust the spacing a bit if you want. Would this be the result you are looking for?